# How to request Authentication Token from StreamSets Control Hub API?

Tags: java, json, rest, streamsets

I am trying to build a JAVA client to POST to a RESTApi, however, while doing so I am getting the error "User not authenticated".

When going through the Documentation for API service, I found I have to obtain an Auth Token before I make the call to API like it says in step 1 and then use the token in any subsquent calls to API.

This is what the Document says:

```
1)
sessionToken=$(curl -s -X POST -d '{"userName":"NAME", "password": "xxxxx"}' https://host:18641/security/public-rest/v1/authentication/login -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "X-Requested-By:SDC" -c - | grep SSO | grep -o '\S*$')
2)
curl -X POST https://host:18641/jobrunner/rest/v1/job/681c449d-7c22-48d6-9532-2e6ef74971bc/start  --header "Content-Type:application/json" --header "X-Requested-By:SDC" --header "X-SS-REST-CALL:true" --header "X-SS-User-Auth-Token:$sessionToken" -i
```

Now, I am not able to achieve the same in JAVA.

I am Using Jersey Library and this is my code so far,

```
public static String testUploadService(String httpURL, File filePath,String User,String Pass,Processing processing)  throws Exception {

  // Thread.sleep(500);

    // local variables
    ClientConfig clientConfig = null;
    Client client = null;
    WebTarget webTarget = null;
    Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = null;
    Response response = null;
    FileDataBodyPart fileDataBodyPart = null;
    FormDataMultiPart formDataMultiPart = null;
    int responseCode;
    String responseMessageFromServer = null;
    String responseString = null;
      String name = User;
    String password = Pass;
    String authString = name + ":" + password;
    String sdc="sdc";
    byte[] encoding = Base64.getEncoder().encode(authString.getBytes());
    byte[] encoding2 = Base64.getEncoder().encode(sdc.getBytes());
    String USER_PASS = new String(encoding);
    String auth2=new String(encoding2);
    String boundary = "=-=" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "=-=";


  // Thread.sleep(500);
    try{
        // invoke service after setting necessary parameters

        ClientConfig cc = new ClientConfig();
        cc.register(MultiPartFeature.class);

        try {
        client = new JerseywithSSL().initClient(cc);
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        webTarget = client.target(httpURL);
        // set file upload values
        fileDataBodyPart = new FileDataBodyPart("file", filePath, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);
        formDataMultiPart = new FormDataMultiPart();

        formDataMultiPart.bodyPart(fileDataBodyPart);


        invocationBuilder = webTarget.request();//.header("Authorization", "Basic " + authString);
                  invocationBuilder.header("Authorization", "Basic " + USER_PASS);
                  invocationBuilder.header("X-Requested-By","SDC");
                 invocationBuilder.header("Content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
        try{response = invocationBuilder.post(Entity.entity(formDataMultiPart, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA));}
        catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        responseCode = response.getStatus();
        System.out.println("Response code: " + responseCode);

        if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
        //    throw new RuntimeException("Failed with HTTP error code : " + responseCode);
        }
    System.out.println("Check 6");
        // get response message
        responseMessageFromServer = 
 response.getStatusInfo().getReasonPhrase();
        System.out.println("ResponseMessageFromServer: " + 
     responseMessageFromServer);
 System.out.println("Check 7");
    processing.setlabel("Finished");
   processing.setprogress(100);

        // get response string
        responseString = response.readEntity(String.class);
             processing.finished("Server Response Code - "+responseCode + "\n ResponseMessageFromServer: "+ responseString);
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error!! \n Make sure you are connected to Dell Internal Network");
        processing.dispose();
    }
    finally{
        // release resources, if any
        fileDataBodyPart.cleanup();
        formDataMultiPart.cleanup();
        formDataMultiPart.close();
        response.close();
        client.close();
    }
    return responseString;
}
```

I need help with fethcing the Auth Token as is done in first Curl command, I am able create the second Post command.

Comment: Mostly Token based login service returns Authentication Token in Response Header. Please check the documentation for key for fetching that response header or any information how this token is returned after authentication. Or Let me know which Token based system you are using ?

Comment: @RohanKadu this is the link to sample code that documentation has,[link](https://github.com/streamsets/datacollector/blob/07c1dd23369ad55a30cd039d96751155a7dbfe8b/container/src/main/java/com/streamsets/datacollector/restapi/AdminResource.java#L164) I am not able figure out in this, newbi to REST!

Answer (score 0):

Parse your response headers and get the authentication token. Look at line number 192 of code you shared

```
String userAuthToken = response.getHeaderString(SSOConstants.X_USER_AUTH_TOKEN);
```

And use this `userAuthToken` in request headers while calling other webservices.You can store this AuthToken in active session. Check Line number 206

```
.header(SSOConstants.X_USER_AUTH_TOKEN, userAuthToken)
```

Key for getting Auth Token is

```
String X_USER_AUTH_TOKEN = "X-SS-User-Auth-Token";
```

Answer (score 0):

The key to this is that the first `curl` command fetches the token, but it comes back in the cookies - hence the `-c -` argument to tell `curl` to write cookies to standard output. The rest of that line extracts the value of the relevant cookie. Check out the Jersey docs for how to access cookies after making a request.